# Code containing bitwise operators fails test cases

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the task:

> Given set `S = {1,2,3,..., n}`, find:
>
> - the maximum value of `a&b` which is less than a given integer `k`, where `a` and `b` (where `a < b`) are two integers from set `S`.
> - the maximum value of `a|b` which is less than a given integer `k`, where `a` and `b` (where `a < b`) are two integers from set `S`.
> - the maximum value of `a^b` which is less than a given integer `k`, where `a` and `b` (where `a < b`) are two integers from set `S`.

My code doesn't work although I can't find a mistake

There's the following test case:

Input: `5 4`

Output:

```
2
3
3
```

However my output is:

```
1382045904
24
3
```

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
    int max_and, max_or, max_xor = -1;

    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        for (int b = a + 1; b <= n; b++) {
            int currently_and = a & b, currently_or = a | b, currently_xor = a ^ b;

            if ((max_and < currently_and) && (currently_and < k)) {
                max_and = currently_and;
            }
            if ((currently_or > max_or) && (currently_or < k)) {
                max_or = currently_or;
            }
            if ((currently_xor > max_xor) && (currently_xor < k)) {
                max_xor = currently_xor;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", max_and, max_or, max_xor);
}
```

Comment: The problem can be rephrased as "find a and b \in S such as a&b (or a|b or a^b)==k-1". There are generally several solutions depending on the operator and on the number of 0/1 in the set and these solutions can be found with bitwise operations, left/right most set bit, etc.

Comment: This rephrasing assumes k-1 \in S. Otherwise the maximal value will be n. There is always a solution, except if k-1==n and n only contains ones, in which case there is no solution with a,b \in S and a<b. In that case, the solution will be n-2. For other operators | or ^, there is always a solution in S with k-1 or n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_and` and `max_or` are not initialized in your code, so they contain garbage values.

More specifically,

```
  int max_and, ...
  for(int a = 0; a < n; a++){
      for(int b = a + 1; b <= n; b++){
          int currently_and = a & b, currently_or = a | b, currently_xor = a ^ b;
          if ((max_and < ...
```

tries to read from `max_and` before it has been set. This accesses an indeterminate value, so the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: initialising the variables like you mentioned and also perhaps one should use unsigned int for binary bitwise operations...

Comment: nitpicking but with most compilers "uninitialized" value can be determined beforehand, ofc not wise or recommended...

Comment: @SampoSarrala I don't believe you.

Comment: @SampoSarrala: what do you mean by *with most compilers "uninitialized" value can be determined beforehand*?

Comment: @chqrlie just that it is predictable, not random. ofc there's ways to make it a little bit more randomized when kernel does ASLR but even then it is be possible to craft probable values before allocation. It requires special care and functionality to make values truly unpredictable and this will have high impact on performance unless done in hardware. Most compilers wont add that functionality as it is something that kernel or special hardware should handle whever required.

Comment: @SampoSarrala You're assuming the code will actually read from memory at runtime. The compiler could just turn the whole thing into a no-op. Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @melpomene no, I'm not saying that it is not undefined. I'm saying that it is not indeterminate. Undefined behavior means that compiler can do whatever it wants not that it will do random things, if it is noop then there's no value and that too can be predicted. I believe you know that well and that is exactly why I stated that whole thing is just nitpicking..

Comment: @SampoSarrala "Indeterminate value" is a technical term from the C standard, defined as "*either an unspecified value or a trap representation*". And in the section about automatic variables (6.2.4): "*The initial value of the object is indeterminate.*"

Comment: @melpomene well, looks like my nitpicking only stands in layman terms. Thanks for pointing that out, I think showing definition from std makes it a lot more clear what exactly might happen with uninitialized things.

Answer (score 0):

`max_and` and `max_or` are **not initialised**.

Uninitialised values in C contain garbage value which is usually some large positive integer.

Initialise them to 0. Also, it is advisable to use *long* type since the evaluated values can become very large.

`long int max_and = 0` and `long int max_or = 0`

Comment: The diagnostic is correct but the advice is not: type `int` is sufficient as long as `a` and `b` have type `int`.

Comment: Yes, in this case `int` is sufficient.